# Cannot upload file from React frontend to ASP.NET Core backend using HotChocolate graphQL

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, file-upload, graphql, multipartform-data

I cannot send file to API. Please help...

Frontend: React

- Library: "@apollo/client": "3.6.9",

Backend: ASP.NET Core

- Package: HotChocolate.AspNetCore v12.12.0

Frontend code:

```
return (
    <div className="h-[130px] mb-4">
      <div className="mb-2 px-2">
        <input
          type="file"
          required
          onChange={({
            target: {
              validity,
              files: [file],
            },
          }) => {
            if (validity.valid) uploadDocuments({ bookingId: 3183, file });
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
-----------Hooks:-------------
  const [
    uploadDocumentMutation,
    { loading: pendingUploadDocuments },
  ] = useUploadDocumentsMutation({
    onCompleted: response => {
      return response;
    },
    onError: error => {
      return error;
    },
  });

  const uploadDocuments = (input: { bookingId: number; file: any }) => {
    console.log('~~~input', input);
    uploadDocumentMutation({
      variables: {
        bookingId: input.bookingId,
        file: input.file,
      },
    });
  };
```

Backend API code:

```
public async Task<bool> UploadBlobFiles(long bookingId, IFile file)
{
    await using var stream = file.OpenReadStream();

    return true;
}
```

I can see logs

[image]

But in the request, file is empty:

[image]

[image]

If anyone knows what is the issue please reply.

Thank you.

I can send file using bananan cake Pop but not front-end